Using Excel O365, How to use unique on two columns, sort, and copy over related data?
I have a 4 column, dynamic row array with names, process, order #, and dates. The array is dynamic and being collected using FILTER() function and grabbing the 4 columns I want from a table on a different sheet.
=FILTER(WelderQualifications[[Employee Name]:[Date Performed]],
 {1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1})

I need a Non-VBA solution to find unique values using only the first two columns (ie. Person 1 GTAW and Person 1 MGTAW are collected but the older Person 1 GTAW date gets ignored.)
Also need it to grab the most recent record when selecting the unique data, maybe a preliminary sort?
Finally, I want to show all 4 columns of filtered data but I don't want the order number or date to be part of the UNIQUE() FILTER(). See image.
Sample data and desired filtered results




Name
Processes
Order #
Date




Person 1
GTAW
438113
10/29/2022


Person 1
GTAW
159623
9/4/2020


Person 1
MGTAW
478734
8/13/2021


Person 2
GTAW
968533
4/22/2021


Person 2
GTAW
864934
3/6/2021


Person 2
VPPAW
841763
2/22/2022


Person 3
GTAW
916397
10/23/2022


Person 3
GTAW
573528
11/21/2023


Person 3
MGTAW
488440
9/1/2022


Person 3
GTAW
224110
6/18/2021




Outputs:



Name
Processes
Order #
Date




Person 1
GTAW
438113
10/29/2022


Person 1
MGTAW
478734
8/13/2021


Person 2
GTAW
968533
4/22/2021


Person 2
VPPAW
841763
2/22/2022


Person 3
GTAW
573528
11/21/2023


Person 3
MGTAW
488440
9/1/2022




I can get the unique two columns to work but I'm not sure how to collect the related data I need.
This sorts the persons name and the process correctly but drops the other two columns obviously:
=UNIQUE(SORT(FILTER(WelderQualifications[[Employee Name]:[Date Performed]],
{1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}),1,1),FALSE,FALSE)

Name and process filtered




Name
Processes




Person 1
GTAW


Person 1
MGTAW


Person 2
GTAW


Person 2
VPPAW


Person 3
GTAW


Person 3
MGTAW




I've dabbled with the LET() function and some SEQUENCE(), LAMBDA(), and a few other options but can't seem to get the arrays to filter properly.

Try using the following formula:


=LET(
     _Data, A2:D11,
     _Headers, TAKE(_Data,1),
     _Body, DROP(_Data,1),
     _Sort, SORT(_Body,{1,2,4},{1,1,-1}),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(TAKE(_Sort,,2)),
     VSTACK(_Headers,CHOOSEROWS(_Sort,
     XMATCH(INDEX(_Uniq,,1)&"|"&INDEX(_Uniq,,2),
     INDEX(_Sort,,1)&"|"&INDEX(_Sort,,2)))))


And if you need only the first two columns then:


=LET(
     _Data, A2:D11,
     _Headers, TAKE(_Data,1),
     _Body, DROP(_Data,1),
     _Sort, SORT(_Body,{1,2,4},{1,1,-1}),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(TAKE(_Sort,,2)),
     VSTACK(TAKE(_Headers,,2),_Uniq))


Also, could try:
=FILTER(A2:B11,MAP(A2:A11,B2:B11,LAMBDA(α,δ,COUNTIFS(A2:α,α,B2:δ,δ)))=1)


Or, more specifically :
=TAKE(FILTER(A2:D11,MAP(INDEX(A2:D11,,1),INDEX(A2:D11,,2),
 LAMBDA(α,δ,COUNTIFS(A1:α,α,B1:δ,δ)))=1),,2)


Or, without a LAMBDA() helper :
=LET(
     _Data, A2:D11,
     _Body, SORT(DROP(_Data,1),{1,2,4},{1,1,-1}),
     CHOOSECOLS(VSTACK(TAKE(_Data,1),
     UNIQUE(CHOOSEROWS(_Body,XMATCH(INDEX(_Body,,1)&"|"&INDEX(_Body,,2),
     INDEX(_Body,,1)&"|"&INDEX(_Body,,2))))),{1,2}))


If applicable, then can use GROUPBY() presently available in MS365 Office Insiders
=LET(α,SORT(A2:D11,{1,2,4},{1,1,-1}),GROUPBY(TAKE(α,,2),TAKE(α,,-2),SINGLE,,0))


Or,
=GROUPBY(SORTBY(A2:B11,D2:D11,-1),SORT(C2:D11,2,-1),SINGLE,,0)



Brilliant! I attempted something similar to combining and comparing but didn't think to use XMATCH and INDEX to do it. Thank you for your help!

Sounds Great, nice to hear from you and sharing the feedback, glad to help  @Muffinman

If someone else struggles with the spill range operator (#): You can write A1:D11 instead

So, did this using the unique() function:

The output matches the results shown by you and others.

If it would be sorted this would work:
=FILTER(A2:D11,MAP(A2:A11,B2:B11,LAMBDA(a,b,SUM((A2:a=a)*(B2:b=b))=1)))
MAP loops through range A2:A11 as a and likewise for range B2:B11 as b if the sum of A2 up to current row of a and B2 up to current row of b is 1 (first occurrence of the combination of the 2) it returns TRUE else FALSE. This is used to filter the row's of range A2:D11
Else you can't make use of range reference, but can stimulate this using sequence:
=LET(s,SORT(A2:D11,4,-1),FILTER(s,MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(s)),LAMBDA(m,SUM((INDEX(s,SEQUENCE(m),1)=INDEX(s,m,1))*(INDEX(s,SEQUENCE(m),2)=INDEX(s,m,2)))=1))))

MAXIFS
Select the most recent (MAXIF(date_…), record for name and process, and if multiple records are found for the date, select the one with the highest order number (MAXIF(order_num,…):
=LET(
    header, A1:D1,
    data, A2:D11,
    name, INDEX(data, , 1),
    process, INDEX(data, , 2),
    order_num, INDEX(data, , 3),
    date_, INDEX(data, , 4),
    VSTACK(
        header,
        FILTER(
            HSTACK(
                name,
                process,
                order_num,
                TEXT(date_, "m/d/yyyy")
            ),
            (
                date_ =
                    MAXIFS(date_, name, name, process, process)
            ) *
                (
                    order_num =
                        MAXIFS(
                            order_num,
                            name, name,
                            process, process,
                            date_, date_
                        )
                )
        )
    )
)


